# Fastest way to build a variable from a byte list?

Tags: c#

I have a `List<byte>` that contains the bytes of a variable received from the serial port. The type of the variable can vary, we only know the size of the variable in bytes.

```
List<byte> data = new List<byte>();

byteList.Add(0x12);    //test values
byteList.Add(0x34);
byteList.Add(0x56);
byteList.Add(0x78);
byteList.Add(0x9a);
```

**Q1:** Which type is the best to use for a variable when we don't know the type and we will learn it's size at runtime? For now, I declared that variable with the maximum possible size. Should I just declare it as an object instead?

```
public UInt64 value;
```

**Q2:** What is the best&fastest way to copy the corresponding bytes from the `List` to this variable? For now, I tried shifting them byte by byte but it didn't seem like a good way to me. So I wanted to use the `BitConverter` but it is for the arrays not for the Lists.

**Example1:**

```
when varSize = 2;
```

then

```
myVar should get 0x1234 as the value and (Uint16) as the type
```

**Example2:**

```
when varSize = 4;
```

then

```
myVar should get 0x12345678 as the value and (Uint32) as the type
```

**Edit:** 
This is a data logger application. The user gives me the address and size of the variable in the external memory and my application reads that memory from the external device. The user then can choose how to see that variable, he/she can want to see it as an integer or float or double etc. But it's always a **number**.

Comment: "Which type is the best to use for a variable when we don't know the type"? How would you use such a variable?

Comment: *“Which type is the best to use [when] we will learn its size at runtime”* – A byte array.

Comment: What are the possible types, what are the possible sizes

Comment: @poke Yes, that sentence is much more logical. I meant that we don't know the size at the compile time.

Comment: @Saruman The type can be anything and the size is learned at runtime as I said.

Comment: So it could be a string, or a datetime?

Comment: @abdullahcinar The answer is still the same: If you don’t know its size (and especially its type), then collect the values in a byte array. It’s only _at runtime_ when you can determine what type and size it actually is, so you can only convert it _at runtime_.

Comment: @poke I know that we can not choose the true declaration at compile time since it will be learned at runtime. I just wanted to ask that: should I just declare it as an `object` then do boxing/unboxing according to the size?

Comment: @John I added the explanation to post.

Comment: @abdullahcinar Boxing something into an `object` has no effect on its runtime type. You will have to parse it at some point, and you can only do that at runtime as per your own explanations. So you cannot have a *compile time type* for this. You will have to branch depending on what type you want to look at.

Comment: @poke I get that, thanks. What about the second question?

Comment: What about little endian and big endian issues? which way around is the source byte sequence?

Comment: @Phill I didn't mention about it since it was not the main issue. But this system uses little endianness.

Comment: "So I wanted to use the BitConverter but it is for the arrays not for the Lists" arrays and lists are easily interchangeable, often transparently so.

Comment: @Phill So you recommend to convert my List to Array? then use BitConverter?

Comment: I am, MyList.ToArray() should do the job for a BitConverter input?

Comment: @Phill But do we have to check the size and use different lines for every size? For example, `BitConverter.toUint64` always gets 8 byte from the array. I have to use `BitConverter.toUint32` when the size is 4.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the BitConverter. The List can be used when calling ToArray()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=netframework-4.7.2

With these function you can parse numbers with length 1, 2, 4 and 8. integer, signed/unsigned and floating point numbers.

Comment: how can we use `BitConverter` on `List`s? I tried using `BitConverter.toUint64` but it only works for arrays.